# getting redirect_uri_mismatch while reading emails from gmail api

Tags: .net-core, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to read emails with .net core app. I have defined authorized uri as https://localhost:44345 on both sides. But when I ran the application I got uri as
redirect_uri: http://127.0.0.1:57944/authorize/ and port no is changing on every try. What should I do

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example].

Answer (score 0):

Your application is sending a redirect uri of `http://127.0.0.1:57944/authorize/` from this I can gather that you are using the google .Net client library.  This is the standard redirect uri created by this library.

This redirct uri must exactly match one that you have added in Google developer console. So you need to add that exactly.   Your ide is chaining the port you will need to fix that so that it runs a standard port rather than a random one each time or its not going to work.

- [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)
- [web-applications-asp.net-core-3](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3)